# Turtle Text Flashing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

When I attempt to put text over a turtle in the python turtle module, it flashes. Any solutions?

```html
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
s.setup(width=500,height=600)

c = turtle.Turtle()
c.shapesize(stretch_len=5,stretch_wid=5)
c.goto(0,0)
c.shape("square")

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0,0)
pen.color("red")

while True:
  pen.write("hello!")
  s.update()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see the flashing on my screen, my guess is your problem is related to this bad idiom:

```
while True:
  # ...
  s.update()
```

We need neither the `while True:` (which has no place in an event-driven environment like turtle) nor the call to `update()` (which is not needed given no previous call to `tracer()`).  Let's rewrite this as turtle code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=500, height=600)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shapesize(5)
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.stamp()  # stamp a square so we can reuse turtle

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.color("red")
pen.write("Hello!", align='center', font=('Arial', 16, 'normal'))

screen.exitonclick()
```

Does that solve your problem?